# ¿cómo puedo hacer que el select 2 cambie cuando lo hace el select 1 con una clase?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Lo que sucede es que necesito que `select 2 "familias"` cambie cuando se elige una orden de especies `select 1`, pero solo cambia el del primer `id`.

Intenté como se ve seleccionarlo por la clase, pero solo cambia la familia de acuerdo al orden de la primer ventana.

Debido a que esta parte de un formulario está presente en diferentes v. modales no quiero repetir ese mismo código para cada ventana

Lo modifiqué según tu comentario @Excorpion, pero el select 2 'familias' se muestra vacío ahora

CODIGO PHP -------------------------------------------

```
$orden=$_POST['orden'];

$sql = "SELECT 
            orden,
            familia
        from ordenes 
        where orden='$orden'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$cadena = "<select name='familia' class='form-control familia2'>";

while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $cadena = $cadena . '<option value=' . $ver[1] . '>' . utf8_encode($ver[1]) . '</option>';
}

echo  $cadena . "</select>";
?>
```

CODIGO JS--------------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ordena').val(1);
    recargarLista();
    $('.ordena').change(function() {
        recargarLista();
    });
})

function recargarLista() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ordenes2.php",
        data: "orden=" + $('.ordena').val(),
        success: function(res) {
            $('.familia2').html(res);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML ---------------

```
  <form class="form-horizontal collapse" id="form-'.$filaEspecies['id'].'" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="ordena">Orden</label>
                        <select name="orden" class="form-control ordena" maxlength="50">
                            <option value="Blattodea">Blattodea</option>
                            <option value="Coleoptera">Coleoptera</option>
                            <option value="Lepidoptera">Lepidoptera</option>
                            <option value="Hemiptera">Hemiptera</option>
                            <option value="Hymenoptera">Hymenoptera</option>
                            <option value="Mantodea">Mantodea</option>
                            <option value="Megaloptera">Megaloptera</option>
                            <option value="Odonata">Odonata</option>
                            <option value="Orthoptera">Orthoptera</option>
                            <option value="Sin especificar">Sin especificar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <label for="familia2">Familia</label>
                    <div name="familia" class="form-group familia2">
                    
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería funcionar
El problema parece ser el JS, comprueba a ver que sucede

PHP

```
$orden=$_POST['orden'];

$sql = "SELECT 
            orden,
            familia,
            pais 
        from ordenes 
        where orden='$$orden'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$cadena = "<select name='familia' class='form-control familia2'>";

while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $cadena = $cadena . '<option value=' . $ver[0] . '>' . utf8_encode($ver[2]) . '</option>';
}

echo  $cadena . "</select>";
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ordena').val(1);
    recargarLista();
    $('.ordena').change(function() {
        recargarLista();
    });
})

function recargarLista() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ordenes2.php",
        data: "orden=" + $('.ordena').val(),
        success: function(res) {
            $('.familia2').html(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: gracias por contestar, pero antes de modificar me salía en el segundo select 'familias' lo seleccionado en la ventana uno, como si todos dependieran de del select 1 'ordenes', de tal forma que si cambio el select 1 de la primer ventana, el select 2 'familias' se ve igual en las demás ventanas y ahora aparece el select 2 'familias' vacío

Comment: Agrega los codigos como estan ahora a la publicacion, faltaría además el primer select tambien y su carga